# Finding the Big-O and Big-Omega bounds of a program

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I am asked to select the bounding Big-O and Big-Omega functions of the following program:

```
void recursiveFunction(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }

    recursiveFunction(n - 1);
    recursiveFunction(n - 2);
}
```

From my understanding, this is a Fibonacci sequence, and according to this article here, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-recursive-fibonacci-program/, the tight upper bound is $1.6180^n$. Thus, I chose all the Big-O bounds >= exp(n) and all the Big-Omega bounds <= exp(n). Below are the choices:

```
O(1)
O(log n)
O(n)
O(n^2)
O(exp(n))

Om(1)
Om(log n)
Om(n)
Om(n^2)
Om(exp(n))
```

The answer choices I selected:

```
O(n^2)
O(exp(n))

Om(1)
Om(log n)
Om(n)
Om(n^2)
Om(exp(n))
```

However, it was alerted that a few of my answers were incorrect (not sure which of them). This seems strange, considering that this recursive function mimics the calls of a fibonacci sequence which has a Big-Theta exponential time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1.6180^n$ is not an upper bound to the running time of your program, not even up to multiplicative constants (in fact it is a lower bound).
However $O(\phi^n)$ is a valid upper bound, where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} > 1.618$ is the golden ratio. It is also easy to see that your program takes $\Omega(\phi^n)$ time, so the above upper bound is asymptotically tight.

That said, $\phi^n \not\in O(n^2)$, so that answer is incorrect.
Moreover, $\phi^n \not\in \Omega(e^n)$ since $\phi < e$, so that answer is incorrect too.

Finally, notice that your answers contradict each other since you say that the running time of the program is both in $\Omega(e^n)$ and in $O(n^2)$ but $\Omega(e^n) \cap O(n^2) = \emptyset$.